# radio buttons in ms office 2007 outlook body

Tags: html, email, outlook

I have been searching of some guidance with my problem but no luck till yet.

I am in process of creating feedback form against some questions. I need to send couple of Radio button in outlook body along with questions so that users can click on "Reply & send email with their selected options".

Have tried something at my end but no luck. in place of showing Radio button, outlook showing ( ). Have tried for checkbox as well but outlook shows [ ]

any help on this matter.

my code for HTML email

```
.HTMLBody = "<table border=0 columns=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 
 width=680>
     <TR><td width=680><input type='checkbox'/>Test</td></tr>
 </table><br>"

.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<HTML><BODY><table border=0 columns=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=680>
      <TR><td width=680></td></tr><br><br>"

.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<Font Color = Navy><Font family = Arial><br>Thank you,<br><br><br><br>"

.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<Font size = +1><b>Customer Satisfaction Survey</b></font><br>
      <table border=0 columns=4 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 
width=680>
            <TR><td width=75>Project:</td>
                <td width = 265></td>
                <td width =75>&nbsp</td>
                <td width = 265></td>
            </tr>

           <tr><td>&nbsp</td>
               <td></td>
               <td>&nbsp</td>
               <td></td>
          </tr>
     </Table><br>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses Word as an email editor. So, your HTML markup is rendered by Word. You can try creating a sample HTML document with bullets and then open it in Word. Do you get the same picture?

Read more about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)